# How can I get the rootNodeID of react element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to capture event depend on whether the event target is a special view.
Something like `view._rootNodeID === 'event.dispatchMarker'`.

But there seems to be no way to get `_rootNodeID` because the only reference I can get is not the actual `ReactNativeBaseComponent` but rather something like `baking data instance` used to construct `ReactNativeBaseComponent` . And `ReactNativeBaseComponent` is the one really owns _rootNodeID, if I understand source code correctly.
I can alter react-native source code to achieve what I want but I want to make sure there is no better way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems I always tend to complicate things...Why wouldn't I handle the touch event in that special view directly?
And I must be blind to not notice a property named `_reactInternalInstance` to refer to the actual element. Although doing so will [breaks encapsulation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode).

Answer (score 0):

[ReactInstanceMap](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c78464f8ea9a5b00ec80252d20a71a1482210e57/src/renderers/shared/shared/ReactInstanceMap.js) exists for this.

```
const ReactInstanceMap = require('ReactInstanceMap');

const inst = ReactInstanceMap.get(view);

view === inst.getPublicInstance();
```